# dashboard using html and jquery which can generate graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

i want to make simple dynamic dashboard which can fetch data from json and acording to data it can perform some operation and generate graphs. 
i am beginner have knowledge about html, css and basics of java script and jquery. can anyone please suggest me some demo links from where i can get help.
I need full code/template from which i can get help
1. Menu in which it has some links 
->> after clicking on any of li item it should fetch data from json file and display on same page.
->> after clicking that data it should generate simple graph on the same page. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview

This might help you. It is a full dashboard solution, with easy to make graphs, if you don't like the graphs they use, you can still use google charts, there are several guides, even from google on how to get it working with json

Answer (score 1):

Quite a general question so it's difficult to answer without writing the whole application for you but I'll leave this here anyway, could be of help.

https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard/blob/master/README.md